# How to animate searchbox length from focusing on the textbox class CSS3?

Tags: css

hi there i am currently trying to make a search box(.pullDown) that animates when you :focus on the textbox(.name) and it should change the size of the div below is the code i tried but it only changed the textbox size not the div i wondered if anyone has any advice on how to make it only change the div height i have tried experimenting with nesting classes but could not get the right results

```
.pullDown{  
    height: 150px ; 
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease;  
    transition: width 1s ease, height 1s ease; ;
}
.name:focus, .pullDown{ 
    display:block;
    height:276px !important; 

}
```

thanks very much for your help
p.s. i am looking for a css way to do it only if possible

Comment: Is your textbox floated?

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: could you share your html? .name:focus, .pullDown{ = .pullDown is a "new" css rule for .pullDown

Comment: sorry cant share the html i know thats really unhelpful it would basically just be a div named .pullDown with a textbox .name within it and when you focus on tht text box eg type or click on it i want it to change the height of the div but not the height of the textbox"which is the problem i am confronted with"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVjQG/2/ i created an example in fiddle with diffrent html hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is when the textbox is selected change the `height` of `.search`, which is a parent element of the textbox?

Unfortuantly this is not possible. Css does not support parent selection. You can do this however with javascript/jQuery so when the textarea is focused you change the `height` of `.search`.

**[jQuery example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVjQG/5/)**

Comment: this is good i was mainly looking for a more css only way to do it but i may just use this as i have realised the css only way can lead to many complications thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle, I see that there are a few errors that need to be handled correctly.

First, changing the `display` value of an element will have the same result as readding the element, why no transitions will ever be triggered. To solve this, you will need to make sure that the `input` has the same display value both before and after focus (for example `block` in this case).

Secondly, you are adding transitions to the container div and not the actual input element that you are changing the height of. Transitions are not inherited if that is what you are assuming. You should thus move the transition to `.name` instead.

Thirdly, animation should only be applied between to distinct values, especially when working with input elements who have a tendency to render rather strange between different browsers. In this case, you can for example set the height of `.name` to `1em` or similar.

Lastly, for some reason you first set the height of `.pullDown` to 150px, but then you immediately after overwrites this to 276px. If you want the div to change size when the field is in focus, this is not the way to do this (actually, it's currently not possible to select the parent of an element with CSS). Comma separated selectors are entirely disjunct from each other. A solution to this can be to replace the `height` attribute with a `min-height`. This will ensure that the div expands to fit the form if it grows larger than the div.

[Here's a fiddle to help you out](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVjQG/4/)

Hopefully this will help!

Comment: this is helpfull but i dont want to change the height of .name i only want to change the height of the div basically what i am trying to acheive is the same affect that would happen if you set the .pullDown as ":hover" only i want this to happen through the focus on the textbox (.name) but make it remain the same height

Comment: Sadly, as I wrote in my answer, selecting the parent of an element is not supported in the current version of CSS (it will in CSS4, though!). I guess, the closest you can achieve with css is to add the height to a sibling element when the input is selected.

Comment: thats unfortunate i can change the parent of the element because thats really what i was going for but i will experiment with some jquery then and work round it thanks for your help

Comment: No worries, glad to help. You can of course just simply animate the margin-bottom on the field, but this would push everything under the field down and I assume you actually resizing to reveal something, why I added the extra `div` where you can put any extra content (remember to set overflow: none in that case!).